# How can I 'upgrade' python without internet access?

Tags: python, upgrade, internet, source

I installed Python 3.7 on RHEL by downloading .tgz file from python.org and
using a chain of commands './configure -> make -> make install'

Now I need to upgrade it to Python 3.9.
What should I do?
Can I just download the source of 3.9 and install as if I'm installing it for the 1st time?

The Red Hat system does not have internet access.

Comment: Why would it be any different?

Comment: @pigeonburger If I just install 3.9 without removing 3.7, I'm concerned there would be any conflict or error.

Comment: ah, right. if you want to keep both, simply add them both to your PATH under separate names (e.g. just `python3.7` and `python3.9`). There should be no conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I need to upgrade it to Python 3.9. What should I do? Can I just download the source of 3.9 and install as if I'm installing it for the 1st time?

```bsh
sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.bak
sudo mkdir /usr/local
./configure && make -j $(nproc) && sudo make install
```